# Mobile DApp connecting to Wallet

Tags: flutter, ethereum

I've been trying to create simple mobile app prototype (in Flutter) which would allow you to connect to a Wallet and obtains your address(es). I cannot get the connection working, all the clients I could find are written in JS so my initial approach was to get it working using webview. However none of the libraries worked for me:

- WalletConnect - the generated `wc:` link is not recognized (universal links don't seem to work)
- Metamask - doesn't inject the provider into the webview browser (I'm serving the scripts locally)
- Web3Modal - requires secure server to run

I'm about to try to get local HTTPS server working in the app just to try the `Web3Modal` but I kind of have a feeling that I'm approaching this wrong.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is now [walletconnect_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_dart) package which supports WC protocol for Flutter. I have created [walletconnect_qrcode_modal_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_qrcode_modal_dart) package which uses `walletconnect_dart` to emulate functionality of `@walletconnect/qrcode-modal` npm package.